# How to parse Java arguments with escape characters from command line

Tags: java, command-line

We have a java application with a main method. The main method takes two arguments from the command line. The userName and userPassword and proceeds further.

Given below how this is invoked --  DBConnection "David" "mypassword" (Here DBConnection is the name of the java class with the main method)

The java main method is something like this--

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{

    String userName = args[0];
    String userPassword = args[1];
    ... 

}
```

It all works fine but fails when the password contains escape characters in the end , like 
 DBConnection "David" "mypassword\". In this case, the variable userPassword contains mypassword" because of string escaping. I understand that the java application should be called with string escaping like DBConnection "David" "mypassword\", but this is invoked by a third party software and we don't have control over this. I was thinking if it is possible to somehow handle this scenario in your java application itself so that arguments like "mypassword\" can be parsed correctly.

Comment: it is obvious that escape character removed during further program execution. Depends on how that method written, you can add another escape character (probably it removes only one escape character at the end of the line)

Comment: Yes it is obvious that escape character removed. I am asking if there is a way to detect this in the  DBConnection  main method and handle it. One naive approach would be to check if last character of the string userPassword is ", but that would be true for strings like "David\"" and "David\", so how to distinguish. I am thinking is there any way to handle this from the main method.

Comment: If the third party is invoking the application, then they need to invoke it with the correct arguments. It's not clear what you mean. The escape character is not removed.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I got the point, basically the third  party should invoke my application with proper string escaping.